# Use google marker with place search and direction matrix API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a query about google custom marker, I am able to use custom marker images in simple plain HTML, but unable to use with place search and direction matrix API.

Here is the link of the page where I have used all the code:
http://moubeenfarooqkhan.com/map.php

When you will open it, you will see that there are two marker images, with P and D letter, These I need to use but where?

**Where = type the input and dropoff addrss and you will see that the map will show the route with marker A and B, I need to use my custom marker here, A replace with P and B replace with D.**

the marker P and D are Used by giving my lat and lon, but what I need is the User type pickup and dropoff location and then the function will convert those address to lat and long and then show sthe custom marker.

Is there any one who can help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your "map.php" page. When I check your code; there is a google maps script bottom of the page. However, you added a listener event before the google maps script. You should write all related to google maps code AFTER the google maps script.

```
// Like This
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCNVxZXG3irUq9XVpHIGAoVlnTAdpqAYcc&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>

google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initAutocomplete );

// Other Google Maps Implementations...
```

Comment: well, Thanks for the improvement, but I Think this will not solve my problem

Comment: initAutocomplete function should below the line

"google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initAutocomplete );"

Comment: my code is like this now:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCNVxZXG3irUq9XVpHIGAoVlnTAdpqAYcc&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>

<script>
google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initAutocomplete );

Comment: Ok. I understand. But in this situation; when the page is navigated "google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initAutocomplete );" runs before the implementation of initAutocomplete function. Just change the order these two.

Comment: My problem is not this, Please look at my question again, Other than the issue I have declared, my code is working fine as per my needs :)

Comment: Dear friend ok your code is working fine but if you open console in the chrome developer tools, you will see 2 error. These are "initAutocomplete is not a function" and "Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined". Just look at the console.

Comment: Let me help you. Here is the screenshot. http://i.hizliresim.com/4lNnPA.png

Comment: ok, I will solve it later, but I need custom marker now, can you help me in this ?